# Xcode 10 Warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

Getting following warnings for build in `Xcode 10` GM version

> Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in target 'FirebaseCore')
>
> Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in target 'FirebaseCore')

How to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Is there an Info.plist file in the FirebaseCore target?

Comment: Yes. It has been there for 2 years. This error started coming in Xcode 10 GM as mentioned.

Comment: What does the Podfile look like?

Comment: I have the same issue, however I do not see a plist in FirebaseCore's support directory. This may be a Google issue.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 10 : Comment following lines from the Podfile

```
# Workaround for Cocoapods issue #7606
#post_install do |installer|
#    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
#        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
#        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
#    end
#end
```

It will solve the issue. Above lines we are using in Podfile due to "IBDesignable not works with the frameworks which links with CocoaPods"

IBDesignable's issue is fixed in Xcode 10

[image: DOCUMENTATION]

I have removed this lines and warning is gone away.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: What if you don't have the above lines to comment out in the pod file?

Answer (score 1):

according to Paul Beusterien in here: [Is it harmful to have warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413384/is-it-harmful-to-have-warning-skipping-code-signing-because-the-target-does-not/54431729#54431729)

you have to update to at least CocoaPods version 1.6.0.rc.1, when this problem occurred I used version 1.5.3.

here is what I did to remove this warning:

1. Delete derived data
2. In terminal, remove the current cocoapods using: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
3. install the latest cocoapod version: `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.6.0.rc.1`
4. change directory to your project, then
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod install`
7. clean and rebuild the project in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is to make a info.plist and add it to your project. Also remember to add it to the build settings of your target. This way the warning goes away.