# Is it harmful to have warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, appstore-approval, xcode10

I have this warning on my Xcode 10 after installing firebase core and crashlytic:

> Warning : Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist
>   file. (in target 'FirebaseCore')

here is the pod I use:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.3'

target 'xxx' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for xxx
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.9.0'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.12.0'




end
```

I have tried to find the solution in here: [Xcode 10 Warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332207/xcode-10-warning-skipping-code-signing-because-the-target-does-not-have-an-info) and in here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1846

but it seems no solution to omit this warning ....

I have tried to remove those pod and install it again (pod install), clean, build, remove derived data etc, but the warning is still there....

and when I try to run the app on my actual device with this warning, I have error:

> Certificate has either expired or has been revoked

Even though this error is easy to solve by Deleting all provisioning profiles at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` and I can run the app on my actual device.

so my question is ....

can I still publish my app to the app store without any problem ? to be honest I am a beginner and I am still confused about code signing related, it makes me worried because I have to delete manually all provisioning profile `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles` over and over again if I want to install the app to my real device from the Xcode 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the warning, update to at least CocoaPods version 1.6.0.rc.1

The warning is not harmful because `FirebaseCore` is a static library that gets linked at build time.